# user interaction in identity inspector vs. attribute inspector

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, user-interaction

I have a `UITableViewController`, I've set the user interaction of the identity inspector to NO (uncheck) and in the attribute inspector it's set to YES (checked), as a result when the user clicks on a cell it doesn't get selected and the embedded control (a checkbox) get the tap event and is checked/uncheck. This is the behavior I'm looking for but since i've set it in the IB it works only for the first cell in a section and I want it to behave the same for all cells.

how can I set programmatically the user interaction of identity inspector?

Answer (score 0):

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, use the cell.userInteractionEnabled property.

Comment: that's the one of attribute inspector, I need the identity inspector